# Print an image on Android Studio

Tags: android, printing, bitmap

Hello everyone I've just finished reading the official documentation about the new printing system in Android Studio (https://developer.android.com/training/printing/photos.html) but I wasn't able to make it work.
I've basically copy-pasted this code:

```
private void doPhotoPrint() {
    PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(getActivity());
    photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.droids);
    photoPrinter.printBitmap("droids.jpg - test print", bitmap);
}
```

But the Android print user interface doesn't appear.

My scope is to set up a printer (where I will print all my photos) and once the setup is complete I will give the printer the Bitmap to print.
I will be greatful to everybody who answer me even for explaining how printing works.
Thank you, S.

Comment: "I wasn't able to make it work" -- we cannot help you if you do not explain, in detail, what you mean by this.

Comment: Have you checked to see if `bitmap` is `null`? Perhaps there is some issue in decoding the resource. I just ran [my book's sample printing app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Printing/PrintManager), and I was able to "print" a photo, insofar as the standard print UI appeared. My code is fairly close to yours, except that I allow the user to pick an image, rather than use a drawable resource.

Comment: You were right, the bitmap was null.
Between is it possible to setup the printer only once for multiple documents?
I will explain myself: can I setup the printer without printing and then print multiple files with the initial setup and without other user interactions?

Comment: There will be one round of user interactions per document that you print. Five calls to `printBitmap()` will result in five documents. If you want only one document, you will have to use something else (e.g., `WebView` and a single Web page containing all of your images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the Android print user interface doesn't appear

Apparently, `PrintHelper` fails quietly with a `null` `Bitmap`, rather than throwing a `NullPointerException` or something else.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void doPhotoPrint() {
    PrintHelper photoPrinter = new PrintHelper(this);//can use getActivity() here

    photoPrinter.setScaleMode(PrintHelper.SCALE_MODE_FIT);

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logontig);

    photoPrinter.printBitmap("myLogo.jpg", bitmap);
}
```